# Site summary feed of Wikipedia excluding a single user

Tags: xml, xpath, awk, xmllint

There is a "Recent changes" feed available on the Wikipedia homepage.

The same is also available as an ATOM feed. It is also possible to watch a single user by going to their user_account and selecting the feed.
But is there any way to get to the feed excluding one (or two) users?

---

Update: Using xmllint I can extract the author names.

```
wget https://hunspell.s3.amazonaws.com/temp/out.txt

xmllint --xpath "//*[name() = 'feed']/*[name() = 'entry']/*[name() = 'author']/*[name() = 'name']" out.txt
```

But I want to exclude one or two authors from this feed. For example, Clarityfiend and Shortride.

---

Update:

When I tried xpath command, it worked very well with one parameter (english). But it failed with a Unicode parameter:

```
wget https://hunspell.s3.amazonaws.com/todel/out.txt
```

worked:

```
xpath -e "/feed/entry[author/name!='Aditya tamhankar' and author/name!='Sushant Madhale']" out.txt > a.txt
```

did not work:

```
xpath -e "/feed/entry[author/name!='Aditya tamhankar' and author/name!='संतोष गोरे']"  out.txt > filtered.txt
```

The entry by the second author is still there in filtered output.

```
grep 'संतोष गोरे' filtered.txt
```

---

The second command is OK with Unicode, but it does not display one  record correctly...

```
# (t1='Aditya tamhankar' ; t2='संतोष गोरे'; echo 'setns x=http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom'; echo "cat /x:feed/x:entry[not(x:author/x:name[.='$t1'] | x:author/x:name[.='$t2'])]/descendant::*[self::x:updated or self::x:title or descendant-or-self::x:name]/text()") | xmllint --shell out.txt  | tail -n +4 | gawk '{ if(NR % 6 == 0){ print $0 "¬"} else { print $0 }}' |gawk 'BEGIN{FS="\n -------\n" ; RS="\n -------¬\n"; OFS="||"} { print $2,$1,$3 }END{ print FNR}'
```

All records except this one are correct:

```
152.238.27.63
/ >
||2021-07-15T20:14:03Z||
19
```

Comment: It's possible I think, I will take a look later. What information are you trying to get from this, users' atom feed?

Comment: Added my answer.

Comment: Updated my answer: discard first 3 lines, filter out ` -------` lines, add a `\n` every 3 lines, changed `FS and RS` on last awk command. Works with `'संतोष गोरे'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you use `xpath` tool from your terminal (Ubuntu package `libxml-xpath-perl`). It supports XPath 2:

```sh
wget -O - https://hunspell.s3.amazonaws.com/temp/out.txt | xpath -e "/feed/entry[author/name!='Clarityfiend' and author/name!='Shortride']" > filtered.txt
```

**UPD**: If there is an out of memory error for input buffer, download the feed into a file rather than standard output:

```sh
wget https://hunspell.s3.amazonaws.com/temp/out.txt
xpath -e "/feed/entry[author/name!='Clarityfiend' and author/name!='Shortride']" out.txt > filtered.txt
```

The XPath query will list all entries with author's name not equal to *Clarityfiend* or *Shortride*. The entries will be saved in `filtered.txt`.

Comment: getting an error: Ran out of memory for input buffer at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.28/XML/Parser/Expat.pm line 478 on m3.2xlarge instance of AWS

Answer (score 1):

You can install *[AbuseFilter](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Special:MyLanguage/Extension:AbuseFilter)* and define a rule that will [tag](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:AbuseFilter/Actions#Tagging) edits made by all but that one or two users (use the variable `user_name` in the filter.

Then you can filter recent changes with that tag. The URL of the Atom feed for recent changes tagged, e.g. "Android app edit", will look like this: https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?tagfilter=android+app+edit&urlversion=1&action=feedrecentchanges&feedformat=atom.

This, of course, holds, if you don't literally mean *Wikipedia* but a wiki that you control.

**OR**

You can feed all recent changes (e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?urlversion=1&action=feedrecentchanges&feedformat=atom) and filter them with an XPath like `/feed/entry[author/name[text()!='Linason Blessing']]` to exclude changes by *Linason Blessing*. See the [saved XPath](http://xpather.com/fLz6ozGk).

Comment: AbuseFilter isn't an option to use on Wikipedia as it's only available to admins and even then, it shouldn't be used to do something like this.

Comment: XPath is the right solution for my use case. But I did not understand how to subscribe feed of changes excluding the user Linason Blessing.

Comment: xpather.com website is very useful, but it does not allow me to subscribe the processed feed.

Answer (score 1):

This Bash one-liner using `xmllint` will filter by `author/name` containing the 2 strings defined in `t1` and `t2` variables and output `update||title||author` values

```
(t1='संतोष गोरे' ; t2='ñandú'; echo 'setns x=http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom'; echo "cat /x:feed/x:entry[not(x:author/x:name[contains(text(),'$t1')] | x:author/x:name[contains(text(),'$t2')])]/descendant::*[self::x:updated or self::x:title or descendant-or-self::x:name]/text()") | xmllint --shell wiki.xml  | tail -n +3 | gawk '!/ -------/ { if(NR % 3 == 0){ $0=$0 "\n"}else{$0=$0} { print }}' | gawk 'BEGIN{FS="\n";RS="\n\n"; OFS="||"} { print $2,$1,$3 }END{ print FNR}'
```

Filtering expression type: `x:author/x:name[not(contains(text(),'$t1'))]`

**Result**:

```
2021-07-15T22:34:54Z||Fabiano Leismann||Simione001
2021-07-15T22:34:53Z||Arnold Henry Mason||4meter4
2021-07-15T22:34:53Z||User talk:MrOllie||152.168.57.106
...
...
```

This will do the same but with exact match on `author`

```
(t1='संतोष गोरे' ; t2='ñandú'; echo 'setns x=http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom'; echo "cat /x:feed/x:entry[not(x:author/x:name[.='$t1'] | x:author/x:name[.='$t2'])]/descendant::*[self::x:updated or self::x:title or descendant-or-self::x:name]/text()") | xmllint --shell wiki.xml  | tail -n +3 | gawk '!/ -------/ { if(NR % 3 == 0){ $0=$0 "\n"}else{$0=$0} { print }}' | gawk 'BEGIN{FS="\n"; RS="\n\n"; OFS="||"} { print $2,$1,$3 }END{ print FNR}'
```

Filtering expression type: `x:author/x:name[not(.='$t1')]`

To filter only one author:

```
(t1='संतोष गोरे'; echo 'setns x=http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom'; echo "cat /x:feed/x:entry[not(x:author/x:name[.='$t1'])]/descendant::*[self::x:updated or self::x:title or descendant-or-self::x:name]/text()") | xmllint --shell wiki.xml  | tail -n +3 | gawk '!/ -------/ { if(NR % 3 == 0){ $0=$0 "\n"}else{$0=$0} { print }}' | gawk 'BEGIN{FS="\n"; RS="\n\n"; OFS="||"} { print $2,$1,$3 }END{ print FNR}'
```

Or generate a UUID and assigned it to `t2` ;-)